# Vim can't detect if a file is vim file type by commenting a file with vim:ft=vim

Tags: filetype

It used to work by adding following line into a file even it has no suffix `.vim`, my vim version is `v8.0.1500`, on `OS X 10.13.3`

```
" vim:ft=vim
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried adding following two lines to **$MYVIMRC**, after `filetype plugin indent on`

```
set modeline
set modelines=5
```

And changed

```
" vim:ft=vim
```

to

```
" vim:set  ft=vim
```

Still doesn't work :(

**Here is my [.vimrc](https://github.com/kenshinji/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/.vimrc) for reference, and for example, [this file](https://github.com/kenshinji/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/rcplugins/ale) couldn't be detected as a vim file.**

**SOLUTION**

1. Add following two lines to **$MYVIMRC**, after `filetype plugin indent on`

> ```
> set modeline
> set modelines=5
> ```

2. use `" vim:ft=vim` or `" vim:set  ft=vim:` instead of `" vim:set  ft=vim`

Comment: Do you have something along the lines of `filetype plugin on` in your vimrc?

Comment: @statox please check my update above :)

Comment: That's a weird problem. If your modeline contains other settings are they applied or are they also ignored? Also how do you check that it doesn't work? (You probably know how to check it properly, it's just to get rid of the obvious :) )

Comment: statox raises a good point. Could you add another setting to the modeline and see if it takes effect? Something obvious like `nomodifiable`. This way you can isolate whether the problem is with your `filetype` settings or your modeline detection.

Comment: @statox What do you mean by "modeline contains other settings"?? Forgive my ignorance :)

Comment: As ZeroKnight say I was suggesting to set `nomodifiable` in your modeline to be sure that the modeline is working. But I see from your update that Wang Shidong's answer was what you were looking for :)

Comment: Your first step is same as solution , why `Still doesn't work :(`?

Comment: @WangShidong I guess I should remove `:` in my first step. my bad.

Answer (score 5):

As Naumann pointed out, `modeline` has to be set on.  This is the default if you're not root.

Your modeline also has to be within `modelines` (default 5) lines from the top or bottom of the file in order to be detected.

You should also test that the settings work when you set them manually.  You might be missing a dependent setting like `filetype on`.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need make sure your `modeline` is on. Check it via `set modeline?`.

Then, update the last line to

```
" vim:set  ft=vim:
```

You need to add an `:`

BTW, new `modeline` will not be executed until some `autocmd` is called, for example.

1. open a new empty file
2. add `" vim:set  ft=vim:` to then end

Then, you will see the file type will not have changed.

Then, if you use `:w` or `:e`, the filetype will change.

Comment: wait, `modeline` and `modelines` are two different things, right?

Comment: @kenshinji Correct. The former enables or disables modelines entirely. The latter defines how many lines from the beginning or end of the file your actual modeline must be in order to be recognized. See Karl Bielefeldt's answer.

Comment: Sorry, I just update the answer, Thanks for you info.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `:set modeline` (e.g. in your `~/.vimrc`).

Comment: That shouldn't be needed since `modeline` is on by default: [`:h 'modeline'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27modeline%27)

Comment: @statox I think it depends on the system you are using, please check [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic), it says "Debian, Ubuntu, Gentoo, OSX, etc. by default disable modelines for security reasons."

Comment: @kenshinji Interesting I didn't know these distros did that.